# Apple Magic Mouse scrolling in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, magic-mouse

Just received new Apple Magic Mouse and tried to install it on my computer with Ubuntu 9.10.

Mouse was found as Bluetooth mouse, I entered PIN as 0000 (could not find it in user manual, so just googgled it). Now I have 2 buttons working well - left and right, but scrolling does not work.

I understand that there is no driver for Magic Mouse for linux, but maybe some enthusiasts already found way to enable scrolling. Without scrolling with only 2 buttons this mouse is just like my first mouse I bought in 1997, Mitsumi as I can remember =)

Answer (score 3):

With kernel 2.6.34 the Magic Mouse driver is included, so scrolling should just work(tm).

I have Ubuntu 10.04 and updated to linux-image-2.6.35-23-generic, and scrolling is working without any other configuration.  It doesn't look like 2.6.35 is available in karmic-backports or updates.  So you would either have to upgrade to 10.04 or 10.10 or build your own kernel.

Answer (score 2):

there is a driver for this mouse but it's very recent and you have to compile it yourself:
http://github.com/entrope/linux-magicmouse

Answer (score 0):

So far no, the magic mouse does not have a standard way to provide scrolling information. As best as I can discover, the pairing process checks the "PNP Information" profile to find the Manufacturer and Product IDs (to match Apple/Magic Mouse) then sends some HID Feature reports to enable the special features of the touch surface and set the device name. Then, the mouse sends reports of the finger touch data and I don't know what they mean. Going from the HID descriptor, it may be that there is an array of sensors on the surface of the device that just show finger positions.

Sorry I don't have a mouse or a mac (or ubuntu :) so I can't provide any more information about this and am unable to experiment at this time.

I suspect the driver will need to interpret the sensor array data manually for single and multi-touch and generate its own 'scroll' and 'pan' events, along with middle-click if required and any other kind of swipes..

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that someone created [an xorg input module and posted it on GitHub](http://github.com/cosmonaut/xf86-input-magicmouse).  Maybe that will be of use to you.

There is also some [Ruby code to get at the mouse's functionality](http://github.com/pedrofranceschi/MagicMouse/).

Comment: Looks like Ruby code is useless for me as it has "Mac OS X with Bluetooth" in its requirements.

Comment: This code might help when/if it matures
http://github.com/entrope/linux-magicmouse