# Using the Apple Magic Mouse on Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, mouse, magic-mouse

Does someone know how to get Apple Magic Mouse working under Ubuntu 9.10? I can upgrade to 10.04 if I need to get Magic Mouse to work.

I read [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/79227/apple-magic-mouse-scrolling-in-ubuntu-9-10), but it does not say what is the solution for getting the multi touch working for ubuntu

Comment: Please add what version of Ubuntu you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to use the multitouch working under Ubuntu.  The multitouch is coded into Mac OS X, but not Ubuntu.  You might be able to find a program to recognize the gestures though.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware the solution for multitouch in Ubuntu is called uTouch which is going to be [included in Ubuntu 10.10](http://blog.canonical.com/?p=414) (aka Maverick). (There is also some information about uTouch in Ubuntu 10.10 in [this blog post](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/455) from Mark Shuttleworth.)

I don't know if any of this support will be backported to any other Ubuntu releases.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a magic mouse with Ubuntu 9.10 and it works in all ways. However -- I am using VM Ware and I think that is translating the gestures into a form that Ubuntu understands.

Are you using VM Ware and OS X or Ubuntu directly?

Answer (score 0):

Since you see that upgrade solves your peroblem - why not?
I am familiar with compiling kernel and modules, but I would not take the burden of recompiling on every ubuntu kernel update.